# Remove top and bottom padding in text input in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: html, css, forms, firefox, google-chrome

I'm trying to make a input look like plain text.  The aim is to draw a span, when user clicks the span it hides and displays an input that looks like plain text, but editable by the user.

In Chrome and Firefox I cannot get rid of top and bottom paddings, even if I set padding and margin CSS properties to 0.

My CSS looks like this:

```
input.myInput {
    font-family: "segoe ui";
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    outline: none;
    border: 0px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

See that font size is set to 20px.  Chrome and Firefox add 4px padding-top and padding-bottom, so that input is 28px tall, not 20px as expected.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or live demo?

Comment: Thanks Jrod, it actually helped me to see the problem.  Creating the jsfiddle demo I notice that there was no such a problem when creting style from scratch.  My <span> had line-height modified in CSS, and that's why it didn't match the <input> height.  Thanks!

Comment: it might be your placeholder. Select it with `::placeholder` and use relative positioning to bring it "a bit"(e.g., `top: 0.1em;`) down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to reset the `line-height` of the input element to be 20px as well. By default, some browser add 4px (2 top + 2 bottom) to input element's line-height.

Answer (score 3):

As Diodeus suggested, just add height to your input.

```
input.myInput {
    font-family: "segoe ui";
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    outline: none;
    border: 0px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

line-height will not work

Answer (score 2):

It could be your font. Try setting the CSS height of the input directly or try adjusting line-height.